# Nodejs + Phantomjs render PDF from variable

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, phantomjs

I would generate some PDF file in Node.js

I would generate it starting from an HTML variable. (i generate it with ejs)
I'm installed the bridge and i did some tests but something doesn't go fine.

if i try to generate a PDF from an Http:// url it works.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var pdffile =__dirname+'/test.pdf';

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage(function(page) {
    page.open('http://www.google.com',function(err,status){
      page.render(pdffile, function(err){
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

if i try with a HTML into variable....
this example works:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var pdffile =__dirname+'/test.pdf';
var content = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p>my paragraph</p></body></html>';

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage(function(page) {
    page.set('content', content);
page.render(pdffile, function(err){
      console.log(err);
      ph.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

**But... i don't understand the reason why this follow doesn't work**

```
var ejs   = require('ejs');
var fs    = require('fs');
var phantom = require('phantom');
var pdffile =__dirname+'/test.pdf';
var str = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/template.ejs', 'utf8');
var params = {id:2423432};
var html = ejs.render(str, params );
var content = '<html><head></head><body>'+html+'</body></html>';

phantom.create(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage(function(page) {
    page.set('content', content);
page.render(pdffile, function(err){
      console.log(err);
      ph.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

EJS render the content of template file into var, but nothing was render by phantomjs.
I also didn't receive err message, the script stop and no PDF files was generated.

Nobody could help me?

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is mostly working, there may be a timing issue. Try putting the `render` inside of an `onLoadFinished` handler on `page`.

So, your sample would become:

```
  ph.createPage(function(page) {
    page.onLoadFinished = function (){
       page.render(pdffile);
       ph.exit();
    };
    page.set('content', content);
    });
  });
```

You can see a similar question and sample code here: [PhantomJS - Rendering fails to show all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643357/phantomjs-rendering-fails-to-show-all-images)

Comment: Where is the node on this answer?