# PhantomJS - Rendering fails to show all images

Tags: pdf-generation, phantomjs

I have a phantomjs script that is stepping through the pages of my site.

For each page, I use `page = new WebPage()` and then `page.close()` after finishing with the page.  (This is a simplified description of the process, and I'm using PhantomJS version 1.9.7.)

While on each page, I use `page.renderBase64('PNG')` one or more times, and add the results to an array.

When I'm all done, I build a new page and cycle through the array of images, adding each to the page using `<img src="data:image/png;base64,.......image.data.......">`.

When done, I use `page.render(...)` to make a PDF file.

This is all working great...  except that the images stop appearing in the PDF after about the 20th image - the rest just show as 4x4 pixel black dots

For troubleshooting this...

- I've changed the `render` to output a PNG file, and have the same
  problem after the 19th or 20th image.
- I've outputted the raw HTML.  I
  can open that in Chrome, and all the images are visible.

Any ideas why the rendering would be failing?

Comment: Got the versions straightened out. Same problem with version 1.9.7.

Comment: I would like to know how you did it for the first image. [This little script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b67c7ef28d00f2a1aa62) doesn't even output one image in the rendered pdf or png.

Comment: @ArtjomB. See my sample in the answer. I'd suggest that you assign to `content` rather than use `document.write`, using a 2nd PhantomJS page for making the PDF.

Comment: It works well when I [wait a little](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/438bc353879661638d6f). I didn't know that `onLoadFinished` is triggered when `page.content` is changed. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

Solved the issue. Turns out that PhantomJS was still preparing the images when the `render` was executed. Moving the `render` into the `onLoadFinished` handler, as illustrated below, solved the issue.  Before, the `page.render` was being called immediately after the `page.content =` assignment.

For those interested in doing something similar, here's the gist of the process we are doing:

```
var htmlForAllPages = [];
```

then, as we load each page in PhantomJS:

```
var img = page.renderBase64('PNG');
...
htmlForAllPages.push('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + img + '">');
...
```

When done, the final PDF is created... We have a template file ready, with all the required HTML and CSS etc. and simply insert our generated HTML into it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var template = fs.read('DocumentationTemplate.html');
var finalHtml = template.replace('INSERTBODYHERE', htmlForAllPages.join('\n'));

var pdfPage = new WebPage();
pdfPage.onLoadFinished = function() {
    pdfPage.render('Final.pdf');
    pdfPage.close();
};
pdfPage.content = finalHtml;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I extracted this from the real code, which is about 1000 lines of javascript, doing lot of other things too!